# Access Denied on Custom Page deployed to Central Administration

Tags: central-administration, custom-actions, access-denied

I deployed a custom application page to central admin. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798467.aspx

If I am a farm administrator and the central admin site collection administrator I can access teh page with no problem.

However, if I am a farm administrator but a central admin site collection administrator i get access denied.

how can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to give the application page anonymous access.
inherit UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase class like the following

```
public partial class ApplicationPage1 : UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```